# Biased random number sources

Tags: testing, random

I'm not sure what the appropriate terminology is, but in trying to run simulations, I always find it tricky to create good fake data.

I don't have an particular application for this, but let's say I want to play around with some silly stock market predicting algorithm - if I were to just use a standard random number generator to get my test data, it would all hover around .5, even over short intervals, and this wouldn't really produce the kind of data that the stock market usually produces during the day (comparing it to stock charts).  Even if the market closes with no gains or loses, you might still find volatility in the middle - simple random walks don't create those same effects.

I guess you could stack rngs on top of one another, a larger magnitude for a full day value, a smaller magnitude per hour, and magnitude still per second, summing them all together to get a more step-like pattern, but that's really too predicable - you know as a developer where those steps will be, or are likely to be if you randomize the durations.

You could literally simulate individual buyer and seller personalities, I guess, but that's a lot of work and computation.   (As far as I know, real stock market data is not freely available in raw form)

So, might we go to find free, easily accessible, quick-flowing, "interesting" data?

Comment: Well, actually a standard RNG can usually produce various different distributions. You may just happen to be using one that has a peak near 0.5 (like the Gaussian).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naive way to implement stock price movements is to use a [normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (Gaussian) distribution but that doesn't generate realistic data. Gaussian distributions understate the risk of massive drops in price (called the "fat tail" phenomenon).

Back in the 60s, Mandelbrot (yes the fractal guy) showed that [cotton price movements](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=9w15j-Ka0vgC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=mandelbrot+cotton&source=bl&ots=S1EST2ZbwR&sig=ZV6STUxuhY28vjsw5XT3MBqttlw&hl=en&ei=5PWmSvPGKM6IkQXW3YWFCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=mandelbrot%20cotton&f=false) fit a [Levy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution).

Take a look at:

- [Monte Carlo simulated stock price time series and random number generator](http://25yearsofprogramming.com/blog/20070412c-montecarlostockprices.htm);
- [The Generation of Random Variables Having a Levy-Stable Distribution](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/stablerand.htm);
- The GNU maths library has a method for creating a [Levy alpha stable distribution](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/gsl-ref.html#The-Levy-alpha_002dStable-Distributions);

Another thing to consider is that over time, the adjusted (for splits and so forth) price of stocks tends to go up. In statistics terms this is called Heterodasticity, which tends to be undesirable from a modelling point of view. This is factored out typically in two ways:

1. Instead of generating a random series of prices, you generate a random series of price changes (deltas); and
2. You model the logarithm of the series rather than the actual series.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

why use fake data? Why not gather up some random stock data from a few years ago and use those to test your algorithm?

Comment: I agree - if you have access to real data, especially if it's modeling a real world scenario, you want to use the best data you can. Random numbers can be great for certain testing, but depending on the generator you choose it can bias the results in a way that would never happen with "real" data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Google Finance API](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/) to get real stock data for a random symbol from a set of 100 symbols for a random day in the last year. That should provide real data that's hopefully randomized enough for your purposes.