# Good libraries for generating non uniform pseudo-random numbers

Tags: random

I'm looking for known libraries that are able to generate non uniformly distributed random numbers for C, C++ and Java.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534285/non-uniform-random-number-generator-implementation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977354/generating-non-uniform-random-numbers and others. Special case of no closed form distribution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423006/how-do-i-generate-points-that-match-a-histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU Scientific Library (GSL), http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/, provides numerous non-uniform random distributions -- see Chapter 19 of the Manual, "Random Number Distributions".   (Uniform random number generators are in Chapter 17, "Random Number Generation").  The implementation is in C.

Answer (score 5):

I got some interesting responses in this related question:

[Biased random number sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396978/biased-random-number-sources)

Answer (score 3):

For Java, one option is my [Uncommons Maths](https://uncommons-maths.dev.java.net/) library.  It supports Uniform, Gaussian, Binomial, Poisson and Exponential distributions.  There is a [WebStart demo](https://uncommons-maths.dev.java.net/demo/demo.jnlp) so you can see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Alglib's implementations](http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/distributions/), they have a few basic distributions implemented in several languages.

Comment: This link leads algorithms for the calculation of several distribution functions, but I didn't find any algorithms for the calculation of random numbers drawn from the distributions.

Comment: Yes, that's true, you have to use a separate RNG. For example  invpoissondistribution(k, rng.nextDouble()) would give you a Poisson variate with parameter k.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org) has a fairly wide selection of random number generates, plus the ability to filter these through several distributions.

Answer (score 0):

[Numerical Recipe](http://www.nr.com/)s discusses a few algorithms for random number generators.

Comment: Actually i already wrote some algorithms for random number generators: Box-Muller, Rejection method among others.. So i'm just looking for libraries that has the reputation to generate strong random numbers non uniformly distributed

Answer (score 0):

With *C++11* there are a lot of new options available for generating *non-uniform Pseudo-random* numbers in the [random](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header. The sample code below demonstrates some of the possible *non-uniform* distributions possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;

    std::mt19937 e2(rd());

    //
    // Distribtuions
    //
    std::normal_distribution<> dist(2, 2);
    //std::student_t_distribution<> dist(5);
    //std::poisson_distribution<> dist(2);
    //std::extreme_value_distribution<> dist(0,2);
    //std::lognormal_distribution<> dist(1.6, 0.25);
    //std::exponential_distribution<> dist(1);

    std::map<int, int> hist;
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n) {
        ++hist[std::round(dist(e2))];
    }

    for (auto p : hist) {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(1) << std::setw(2)
                  << p.first << ' ' << std::string(p.second/200, '*') << '\n';
    }
}
```

using the *normal* distribution you would see output similar to this:

```
-5 
-4 
-3 
-2 *
-1 ***
 0 ******
 1 ********
 2 *********
 3 ********
 4 ******
 5 ***
 6 *
 7 
 8 
 9
```